# List all associations as links in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, has-many, model-associations

Is it possible in active admin to list all of the `has_many` associations of my record as links?

The code should look something like:

```
column "belongs to" do |b|
    b.associations.map { |a| link_to(a.name, admin_association_path(a) }
end
```

But this generates a list of  tags that aren't rendered as clickable links.

Comment: Is `association` here standing in for a particular association, e.g. `posts`? If so, you're probably just missing a `.html_safe` at then end of your chain.

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map` is producing an array of html strings, so you need to `join` them to get a single string and then mark it as html-safe.

```
column "belongs to" do |b|
    b.associations
     .map { |a| link_to(a.name, admin_association_path(a)) }
     .join
     .html_safe
end
```

Comment: ahh that'll do it. Thanks!